# unable to send email as both plain text and html in cakephp

Tags: php, email, cakephp

```
    App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
    $Email = new CakeEmail();
    $Email->to($emailContentArray['To']);
    $Email->from(array($emailContentArray['From'] => Configure::read('FROM_NAME')));
    $Email->subject($emailContentArray['Subject']);
    $Email->emailFormat('both');
    $response=$Email->send($emailContentArray['Body']);
```

if we check the resulting email it looks like:-

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="782f009f669cbcf2faafff59fe0eeb5d"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Identified-User: {:test25.xyzzzz.com:testttt.com} {sentby:program running on server}

--782f009f669cbcf2faafff59fe0eeb5d
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="alt-782f009f669cbcf2faafff59fe0eeb5d"

--alt-782f009f669cbcf2faafff59fe0eeb5d
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<div>â€‹<BR>Hi<BR><BR>Soon you will reach the action limit. To keep yourself updated please pay the payment.<BR><BR> Happy to&nbsp; have you<BR><BR>Thanks,<BR>Apps Team<BR>â€‹</div>


--alt-782f009f669cbcf2faafff59fe0eeb5d
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<div>â€‹<BR>Hi<BR><BR>Soon you will reach the action limit. To keep yourself updated please pay the payment.<BR><BR> Happy to&nbsp; have you<BR><BR>Thanks,<BR>Apps Team<BR>â€‹</div>
```

In text/plain the email should not show the html tags - how can I get both html and plain text to be sent correctly?

Comment: What is `$emailContentArray['Body']` ? It seems likely to be a html string.

Answer (score 0):

Encode the content and the subject in base64: 
`"=?utf-8?b?".base64_encode($s)."?=";`

And before sending the emails don't forget to set the header:

```
'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64';
```

If I'm not wrong you can make to set header: `$Email->setHeader('X-Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'base64');`

You can take a look at [Cakephp sending UTF-8 Emails and lineLength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17706331/cakephp-sending-utf-8-emails-and-linelength) 
And at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html